# How can I insert row div for every 3rd entry in props?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've got a set of dashboards that display in bootstrap cards on a front page and I would like to wrap them in a div with the class row for every 3rd entry. I was thinking about marking my dashboard component with the DB id from props and use a modulus function, but that will cause problems if an ID is deleted

Dashboard component:

```
export type DashboardProps = {
  id: number
  title: string
  description: string
}

const Dashboard: React.FC<{ dashboard: DashboardProps }> = ({ dashboard }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
        <div className="card bg-light h-100">
          <div className="card-header">
            {dashboard.title}
          </div>
          <div className="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p className="card-text">
              {dashboard.description}
            </p>
            <a className="btn btn-info text-center mt-auto" 
                onClick={() =>
                  Router.push("/dashboard/[id]", `/dashboard/${dashboard.id}`)
                }
            >Go to dashboard</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Index page:

```
type Props = {
  dashboards: DashboardProps[]
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const dashboards = await prisma.dashboard.findMany({
    orderBy: { id: "asc", },
  })

  return {
    props: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ dashboards })),
  }
}

const Index: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  if (status === "loading") {
    return (
      <Spinner />
    )
  }

  if (!session) {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <AccessDenied />
      </Layout>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Dashboards</h1>
        {props.dashboards.map((dashboard) => (
          <Dashboard dashboard={dashboard} />
        ))}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Index
```

I could also potentially wrap them in a single div with class row, but I would need to enforce a top/bottom margin so the cards don't stack right on top of each other. Any tips to get me rolling on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might not be what you're looking for but have you looked into CSS Grid? It sounds like you're trying to implement your own type of grid styling here.

Comment: This is what adding a <div className="row"> before mapping the dashboard props does. However, I'm having difficulties adding top/bottom margin to this grid and it makes the cards stack too tightly with no breathing room.
Inserting the div for every 3rd entry solves the problem, but there might be a css/bootstrap solution to add the margin as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map` provides `index`, you this to find every 3rd element.

```
//...
{
  props.dashboards.map((dashboard, index) =>
    (index + 1) % 3 === 0 ? (
      <div>
        <Dashboard key={dashboard.id} dashboard={dashboard} />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <Dashboard key={dashboard.id} dashboard={dashboard} />
    )
  )
}
```